# DVM instance creation per activity or application

Tags: android, dalvik

For Android, each application has its own instance of DVM or each activity of an application has its own DVM instance i.e. the instance of DVM is created based on the application or activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, each process has its own Dalvik VM. Since normally each application runs in a single process, all activities share the Dalvik VM for that process.

There are more complicated scenarios (one app spread across N processes, N apps sharing one process), but those are very unusual in conventional Android application development.